# google app on iphone - home screen - what is this icon?

Tags: iphone, google-apps

I have been searching both google and apple support for several days, this feature is explained nowhere. There is no callout with a name for it. The only articles with a general explanation of the main features for the app are for how it appeared several releases ago.

Look at my black arrow pointing to it.

[image: The bottom navigator bar button icon in question is pointed to by a black arrow]

This feature acts 2 ways - same icon.

1. When you are viewing a search result page, you hit it and it saves the page in a stack of sorts.
2. When you are in the home screen, it opens up your stack of saved pages.

WHAT IS THIS?

I do not have Chrome on my phone, only the Google app (google search). It does not appear in Safari as bookmarks or reading list entries on the phone. It does not appear in my desktop Google Chrome Search History  under "Tabs from other devices" or in total google activity (myactivity.google.com). It seems to be its own little bookmark island sitting on my phone.

Is there a Google name for this feature?

Answer (score 3):

The app itself refers to it as **recent pages** when first using this feature and when all pages are closed. Any searches you make or pages you open in the app are saved there for future reference. (I previously saw "Recent Pages" at the top of the screen, but I must've been mistaken.)

I would normally call these cards, but I'm uncertain of the exact definition under Google's Material Design specs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clue! But on my phone I see nothing at the top when I touch it. Do you see that in a tablet or a simulator? I do have the smallest iPhone, SE.

Comment: I have an iPhone 7 Plus. I'll add a screenshot of the page on my phone.